# i want to know how can we send and recieve files on android phone?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can u people help me in getting java code to transfer files (FTP) over the LAN.Give me the complete code for this.

I wan that a FTP request to be send to the desired host and if the host accept the request then the browse menu be opened that allows the host to select the file to be transfered.Then by clicking on some button the FTP operation should be completed. The ttransfered file should be saved in an appropriate folder on the client side.

i will be greately thankful to u people.

Comment: www.plzsndmetehcodez.org

Answer (score 0):

apache has a java library for FTP that should work on android.

http://commons.apache.org/net/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add jar file commons net.jar and follow the Link http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=28.
That will be sufficent.